# Wine and Font Awesome have conflicting fonts

Tags: 16.04, wine, fonts

I'm running i3 as my window manager, and I'm using some of Font Awesome's icons to dazzle it up a bit. Only problem is, after installing Wine and playonlinux, most of Font Awesome's symbols don't show up correctly.

I can uninstall Wine and the font starts working properly again.

Anyone know of a fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone who stumbles to this page, I did find a solution.

Open `~/.config/i3/config` and include `FontAwesome` on your font line.

For example, change:

> font pango:monospace 20

To:

> > font pango:monospace, FontAwesome 20

This line is used for overriding the system default settings for fonts. In the case above, i3 will check `monospace` for the proper glyph first, then `FontAwesome`. If it's not found, the system default settings are used.

Hope this helps!